# What happens when session keys are assigned and removed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis, garbage-collection

I'm using session variables to store objects by assigning them to a corresponding session key. Because these variables are session-specific they aren't collected by Garbage Collector, but rather cleared by session timeout. In order to delete these session variables I must remove the key that holds the object I don't want to use anymore.

When assigning an object to a session variable, Does that session key points to the object reference itself or does it create another reference?

And when a session key that holds an object is removed by using .Remove(), Does this removal clears that memory space or does it still exist under the hood but without a related key?

I'm asking this because I want to know if server performance is affected when using several session variables(e.g. big objects in session and many users), to know if removing the keys of the objects that are not going to be used anymore causes a benefit in server memory usage, and also to know what happens under the hood when these keys are removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my basic understanding - when you assign a variable to the session key it will either store its pointer(when it is a reference type) or box it(when it is value type since you are storing general object in the session), thus create a copy of it.

> And when a session key that holds an object is removed by using .Remove(), Does this removal clears that memory space or does it still exist under the hood but without a related key?

It depends on the fact whether reference is considered garbage or not. If nothing points to the stored reference, it will be removed with the nearest GC.

> I'm asking this because I want to know if server performance is affected when using several session variables(e.g. big objects in session and many users), to know if removing the keys of the objects that are not going to be used anymore causes a benefit in server memory usage, and also to know what happens under the hood when these keys are removed.

You shouldn't store big objects in the session because it always hits performance. Big objects are problematic overall(often will be moved to the next GC generation what will result in their extended lifetime - will occupy app memory much longer, can cause memory fragmentation causing garbage collecting lasting longer).

Since `Session` uses indexer internally and its items are stored as `Hashtable` you can consider that `Session` is some kind of an array which is request specific. Take into consideration that since it is passed with each request and has to be stored somewhere, many objects which you add to it will last as long as e.g. user is active. If you have thousands of users and store e.g. 1MB for each, imagine how much memory will be allocated for application lifetime.

Comment: So, for example if I assign an object to a Session variable called "BigObject", and that variable is the only reference to that object, once the key is removed, itI'll be collected by GC. Is that right?

Comment: @jecarfor Exactly. Since both variable and session item are just pointers and don't represent real value itself, once there are no other references to the object, GC will consider it garbage and remove it.